# Using jQuery to display advertising

Tags: jquery, ads

I have a fast server but advertising can really grind the page to a halt. Sometimes an ad can even break the page and if that's the top ad then...

So, I was wondering if anyone had used jQuery to load ads after a page had loaded? In theory, it sounds great. I could load the page in double-quick-time then load the ads.

While I could knock up a few page to test the theory, I'd be more worried about the longer term effect of advertisers not liking the practice. Some don't like ads loading into an iframe, for example. Will they get all the referrer information they want?

I realise advertising is a nasty subject, so I apologise for that.

[UPDATE]

I've created a test page which loads an advert via ajax. The advert is javascript but it replaces my whole page with the advert.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "test.php", data: "ad=1", dataType: "script", success: function(response){ $('#advert').html(response); } });
<div id="advert"></div>
```

I've also used dataType: html with no success.

Comment: how do you want to show the ads? as a pop-up or as a part of page or as an image?

Comment: When you say advertising, what kind of tags exactly are you using on your page?  <script> tags (e.g. from AdSense, from an ad server etc.)?  <a> and/or <img> tags?

Comment: Pop-ups are evil and I refuse them. The ads I want to show are javascript though, which display flash in the most part. Google Adsense is a good example of the ads I'll be using, but not exclusively.

Comment: can you paste in a sample of the 'response'?

Comment: I realise this is html, rather than a script which is why I've tried datatype:html too. <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-99999";
    /* Sponsor - text ad */
    google_ad_slot = "99999";
    google_ad_width = 468;
    google_ad_height = 60;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the following methods:

- [$.getScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085132/)
- [iframe append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107821/)
- [script append](http://www.sitepoint.com/insert-in-place-without-documentwrite/)